# Firefox 31 applies Windows-related zoom on every site

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have read all the topics on this problem. I just installed FF 31 and all the sites that I was viewing got zoomed and distorted.

My question is - how can I stop firefox from using the default Windows-related zoom settings that break the layout.

Comment: please reformulate to a non-offensive question

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to prevent your users from using their browser zoom? Accessibility is probably a great concern for Mozilla—I wouldn't call it lack of common sense, it's a *feature*.

Comment: Thank you for your edit but you need to remember that we have no way to know what nuisances Firefox 31 is doing to your work unless you tell us. Some relevant HTML and CSS, perhaps an online fiddle and maybe a screen-shot can definitively help.

Comment: I cant show nothing too particular about this problem. Every single thing I see in FF 31 is zoomed (yes, using the Ctrl + 0 tip). Chrome and IE are not causing such an issue for me.

Comment: Ah, alright. Stack Overflow is a site *for professional and enthusiast programmers* not for general computer users. You can either find a suitable site on the StackExchange network or ask your question at [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/es/). Now, Firefox complete messed up rendering on high DPI settings on Windows but it was several releases ago, not 31. You'll have to fix it with a couple of addons.

Comment: Yes, I got that straight. But I am wondering about the regular user. Not just my development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl + 0 // zoom to normal